# Custom 404 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-authentication

If we just create a `404.blade.php` page in `resources/views/error` it will work fine, but **Auth()** won't work on 404 page, to solve that if we follow the solution available on stackoverflow the Laravel auth errors will stop working. I use the following solution to do the work.

Comment: Hi, i have a hard time understanding your problem, can you please clarify it and maybe add some code.

Comment: yes it will not work on you 404 page if you want to use auth in 404 page then you have to manually catch the route and create your own controller

Comment: yeah i already have the solution.


create resources/views/errors/404.blade.php (your custom page)

add the below to your routes.php
```
Route::any('{catchall}', 'PageController@notfound')->where('catchall', '.*');
```
Now in page controller use the **notfound** function
```
public function notfound()
    {
        return view('errors.404');
    }
```

This wont affect the auth errors.
I answered on the post, but it was deleted.

Comment: @AkilPatel that's great

Comment: @kamlesh if you can just copy my comment as post that as answer, it will help others as well

Comment: @AkilPatel added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create custom view

`resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`

in route.php

```php
Route::any('{catchall}', 'PageController@notfound')->where('catchall', '.*');
```

create `PageController` and add this function

```php
public function notfound() 
{ 
    return view('errors.404'); 
}
```

Comment: It was very useful. Definitely run for Laravel 8. I actually used Laravel 6 and Laravel 7 and the 404 page was working on them. However, the same methods did not work in some areas in Laravel 8. Especially such an error was emerging.(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, DELETE.) Thanks to this method, this error was fixed in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.6 and later, you can use `fallback` in your `routes\web.php`:

`Route::fallback('MyController@show404');`

It works as an "catch all"-route.

[See docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#fallback-routes).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help. Laravel has a PHP artisan command to publish error pages. [Laravel Custom HTTP Error Pages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

After you run this artisan command use `Route:fallback()` method as @KFoobar suggested. If you use a closure function, no need to use a controller. Make sure to add the below route at the ends of your routes file.

```
   //Fallback/Catchall Route
   Route::fallback(function () {
       return view('errors.layout');
   });
```

Shameless plug for my [**BLOG**](https://david.dukesnuz.com/blog/show-blog-posts)

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in your Exceptions/Handler.php

```
if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
   if(view()->exists('errors.'.$exception->getStatusCode())){
        $code = array('status'=>$exception->getStatusCode());
          return response()->view('errors.404',compact('code'));
       }
   }
```

Now create a new file in your view i.e errors/404;

Now in code array you can pass dynamic values